# Angular field autocomplete HTML5 attribute not working

Tags: html, angular

I'm using Angular 7 and I have this input:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete name="hf-emails" formControlName="emails"/>
```

And the HTML5 autocomplete it's not working. I tried with/without the "name" attribute but still nothing, any ideas?

Comment: Define "not working". Please add an [mcve] and also review the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) especially the requirements.

Comment: I post the form multiple times, still get no list or anything when focusing the input, I also tried autocomplete="email" but no luck

Comment: I tried setting id+name, the input is descendant of form, and the form has a button with type="submit"

Comment: have you tried giving it a value?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code ,

```
    //if you want the auto-complete off
    autocomplete=off
    //for auto complete on , it vice-versa
```

OR

```
    //same applies here
    autocomplete="off"
```

Hope this answer get usefull to you .